# LWC - iconAlternativeText not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

Howdie! I am currently developing an LWC that consists of a lightning-datatable with data fetched from an external endpoint. The first column should be an icon (with an alternative text).

I tried to use the iconAlternativeText as described on the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) but nothing is displayed when I hover over the icon, while the `iconLabel` property is displayed correctly.

This is the current code I have for the first table column:

```
const columns = [

      {
        label: "Type",
        fieldName: "",
        initialWidth: 50,
        hideDefaultActions: true,
        cellAttributes: {
          iconName: { fieldName: "type" },
          iconLabel : 'ICON-LABEL',
          iconAlternativeText : 'Alternative text'
        }
      }
```

Also tried to test this on a [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/qqj-6OQ1/1/edit) but the output is the same.

[image]

Can anyone lead me to what I am doing wrong here?

Best regards and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iconAlternativeText` does not work as a hover text but `title` attribute on `lightning-icon` does that. Unfortunately, `lightning-datatable` only supports following 4 attributes to be passed in icon cellAttributes and `title` is not one of them -

1. iconName
2. iconLabel
3. iconPosition
4. iconAlternativeText

As far as your implementation is concerned, it's working just fine. You may inspect elements and find out that `iconAlternativeText` has added following element

```
<span class="slds-assistive-text">Alternative text</span>
```

As mentioned [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/visibility/#Assistive-Text), `slds-assistive-text` text is picked up by screen readers or similar assistive technologies.

If you really need to show a hover text, you'll have to create custom data type for datatable. Refer "Creating Custom Data Types" [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation). Hope this helps.